# How to put text content into div

Tags: html, css

I have tried a design as like in below image.

[image: clip]

It's all done except one little part. You can see the text "best value" on top right corner. The text was overlapping the element.

When i check with inspect element result shows like in below image.

[image: result]

How to get the text into that `.triangle-skewed` class.
Thanks in advance.

```css
.selected {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  background: #00ADEF;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.selected .plan-title {
  background: #f47129;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 6px 2px 6px 2px;
  position: relative;
}
.selected .plan-title h1 {
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.selected .plan-title .triangle-skewed {
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  border-top: 80px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.selected .plan-title .triangle-skewed p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.selected .plan-content {
  background: #00ADEF;
}
.selected .plan-content .h1-powof {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 74px;
  color: #fff;
}
.selected .plan-content .h1-powof span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.selected .plan-content .month {
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 23px;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p {
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p span {
  color: #fff;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p-margin {
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p-margin span {
  color: #fff;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p-shipping {
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-top: 8%;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p-shipping-no-space {
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
.selected .plan-content .pick-btn {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  background: #f47129;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 80%;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #050505;
  transition: .2s;
}
.selected .plan-content .pick-btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.06);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 plans">
   <div class="plan-box selected">
      <div class="plan-title">
         <h1>ruby</h1>
         <div class="triangle-skewed">
            <p>best value</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="plan-content">
         <h1 class="h1-powof"><span>$</span>49</h1>
         <p class="month">per month</p>
         <p class="content-p">4x 15ml bottles of ejuice</p>
         <p class="content-p">guaranteed 60ml of ejuice</p>
         <p class="content-p">1 pack <span>royal wires by dryx</span></p>
         <p class="content-p">$66 retail value</p>
         <p class="content-p-shipping">free shipping</p>
         <button class="pick-btn">this plan is selected</button>
      </div>
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried using z-index? It will push the element from of the "black triangle" element..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the properties `absolute` and `transform`.

You can read more about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp

```css
.selected {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  background: #00ADEF;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.selected .plan-title {
  background: #f47129;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 6px 2px 6px 2px;
  position: relative;
}
.selected .plan-title h1 {
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.selected .plan-title .triangle-skewed {
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  border-top: 80px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.selected .plan-title .triangle-skewed p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  transform: rotate(42deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  right: 3px;
}
.selected .plan-content {
  background: #00ADEF;
}
.selected .plan-content .h1-powof {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 74px;
  color: #fff;
}
.selected .plan-content .h1-powof span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.selected .plan-content .month {
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 23px;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p {
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p span {
  color: #fff;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p-margin {
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p-margin span {
  color: #fff;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p-shipping {
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-top: 8%;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p-shipping-no-space {
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
.selected .plan-content .pick-btn {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  background: #f47129;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 80%;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #050505;
  transition: .2s;
}
.selected .plan-content .pick-btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.06);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 plans">
                <div class="plan-box selected">
                    <div class="plan-title">
                        <h1>ruby</h1>
                        <div class="triangle-skewed">
                            <p>best value</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="plan-content">
                        <h1 class="h1-powof"><span>$</span>49</h1>
                        <p class="month">per month</p>
                        <p class="content-p">4x 15ml bottles of ejuice</p>
                        <p class="content-p">guaranteed 60ml of ejuice</p>
                        <p class="content-p">1 pack <span>royal wires by dryx</span></p>
                        <p class="content-p">$66 retail value</p>

                        <p class="content-p-shipping">free shipping</p>
                        <button class="pick-btn">this plan is selected</button>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
```

Comment: Oh... Ivin raj also posted the same. As preference accepting ur answer.. Thank you @Hewlett..

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```css
.selected {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  background: #00ADEF;
  text-align:center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.selected .plan-title {
  background: #f47129;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 6px 2px 6px 2px;
  position: relative;
}
.selected .plan-title h1 {
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 13px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.selected .plan-title .triangle-skewed {
  border-left: 100px solid transparent;
  border-right: 0px solid transparent;
  border-top: 80px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.selected .plan-title .triangle-skewed p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
   transform: rotate(42deg);
  position: absolute;
  top: -80px;
  right: 3px;
  
}
.selected .plan-content {
  background: #00ADEF;
}
.selected .plan-content .h1-powof {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 74px;
  color: #fff;
}
.selected .plan-content .h1-powof span {
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 12px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.selected .plan-content .month {
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 23px;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p {
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p span {
  color: #fff;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p-margin {
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin-bottom: 9px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p-margin span {
  color: #fff;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p-shipping {
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-top: 8%;
}
.selected .plan-content .content-p-shipping-no-space {
  color: #050505;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
.selected .plan-content .pick-btn {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 3%;
  background: #f47129;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 80%;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 12px 10px 12px 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px #050505;
  transition: .2s;
}
.selected .plan-content .pick-btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.06);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 plans">
                <div class="plan-box selected">
                    <div class="plan-title">
                        <h1>ruby</h1>
                        <div class="triangle-skewed">
                            <p>best value</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="plan-content">
                        <h1 class="h1-powof"><span>$</span>49</h1>
                        <p class="month">per month</p>
                        <p class="content-p">4x 15ml bottles of ejuice</p>
                        <p class="content-p">guaranteed 60ml of ejuice</p>
                        <p class="content-p">1 pack <span>royal wires by dryx</span></p>
                        <p class="content-p">$66 retail value</p>

                        <p class="content-p-shipping">free shipping</p>
                        <button class="pick-btn">this plan is selected</button>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Applying

```
margin-left: -59px;
margin-top: -68px;
transform: rotate(45deg);
```

to the p element should do the trick?